# Specific Dart Version Environment in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, opencv, dart

At first I want to use this `opencv_4: ^1.0.0` plugin, but it requires `json_serializable: ^4.0.0`

after successfully upgrading all the depedencies I ran this command :

`flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

and it gave me this error :

`Generator cannot target libraries that have not been migrated to null-safety`

I know so many suggest me to update the environment to `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`

and if I updated the environment I should migrate to null safety which is I dont want to because I have so many depedencies that not yet supports null safety.

so I've tried like :

- updating the environment to `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`
- ran `flutter pub get`
- ran  `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`
- downgrading the environment to `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`
- ran `flutter pub get` again

I know this is like dumb way to get rid of any errors but the question is, can I declare the specific environment just for the
 `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` command ?

so I don't have to manually upgrading and downgrading the environment.

Comment: If you need to stay with non Null Safety packages, you should be on old SDK version. You can set fixed SDK version (like `sdk: "2.7.0"`) and try to build your project again.